# How to use R purrr to combine hundreds of Excel files/sheets

Tags: r, excel, import, purrr

I've got hundreds of Excel files with varying quantities of sheets within said files. I want to combine all these Excel files and sheets into one data frame. Lucky for me, all the sheets are in the same format (they're a template filled out by customers and uploaded to a central repository).

Let's simulate these Excel files and sheets with the code below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)
library(readxl)
write.xlsx(list(iris, iris * 2, iris * 3), "three_sheets.xlsx")
write.xlsx(list(iris, iris / 2), "two_sheets.xlsx")
```

How would I use R purrr to combine these files and sheets into one data frame? And can I mutate a column to identify which file/sheet each row comes from? If purrr isn't the best choice for this type of problem feel free to point out other solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`purrr` seems to be a good choice for such operation. You can do :

```
library(readxl)
library(purrr)

#Get full path of all excel files in the folder
all_files <- list.files('path/of/folder',pattern = '\\.xlsx$', full.names = TRUE)
For each file
result <- map_df(all_files, function(x) {
             #Get all the sheet names
             all_sheets <- excel_sheets(x)  
             #read the excel file with one sheet at a time
             map_df(all_sheets, ~read_excel(x, sheet = .x) %>% 
                       #add columns for filename and sheetname
                       dplyr::mutate(filename = basename(x), sheetname = .x))
})
```

Comment: In this example I noticed that the `all_files` function will work whether the `full.names` argument is `FALSE` or `TRUE`. Can you explain the reason you set it to `TRUE`? I'm guessing in other circumstances the `full.names` argument must be set to `TRUE`.

Comment: Yes, if your files are in working directory it will work as well. However, if your files are not in working directory it will give an error stating cannot find the file. I always prefer to use `full.names = TRUE` because it works irrespective if your files are in working directory or not.