Load files in bulk and create new column with file name
I have a folder with 3000+ xlsx files that I need to upload in bulk. The catch? I need to create a new column with the value equal to the file name.
Let's say my files are named id1, id2, id3, and so on, and each file looks like the following:
set.seed(100)
id1 <- data.frame(obs= 1:4,
                      temperature= runif(4),
                      latitude= runif(4),
                      altitude.3= runif(4))

I want each file to have a new column with the name of the file they are originally pulled from. For instance, the new id1.xlsx  file should look like this:
id1 <- id1 %>% 
  mutate(id="id1")


Does this answer it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73625002/add-filename-to-a-new-column-when-using-map-df-in-r or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41006985/importing-multiple-csv-files-into-r-and-adding-a-new-column-with-file-name  --- but use your xlsx importing method in place of read_csv.  Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63840240/how-to-use-r-purrr-to-combine-hundreds-of-excel-files-sheets/63840433#63840433

Are you combining them into one large data frame or do you plan on keeping them in a list?

I will eventually combine them into a large data frame.

You can read the files, bind them, and create this column in one step using the rio package:
# get all excel files from directory
files <- list.files(pattern = "*xlsx$")

rio::import_list(files, rbind = T, rbind_label = "filename")
#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb filename
# 1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 id1.xlsx
# 2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 id1.xlsx
# 3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 id1.xlsx
# 4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 id1.xlsx
# 5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 id1.xlsx
# 6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 id1.xlsx
# ...

Data
This will create 5 Excel files in your current working directory.
n <- 5
replicate(n, mtcars, simplify = F) |>
  setNames(paste0("id", seq(n), ".xlsx")) |>
  purrr::iwalk(~ writexl::write_xlsx(.x, .y))

